# Stored procedure running despite failing at the first step

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, sql-server-2019

I am troubleshooting a stored procedure that is supposed to send data from a SQL Server instance to another SQL Server instance hosted on Azure.

The way the stored procedure works after investigating it is it first figures out based on parameter what tables it is going to transfer.  So I end up with at able variable `@transferTable` that looks like

```
id     tableName
===================
23     tableName1
55     tableName23
72     tableName111
```

Then in a loop, that look is setup like

```
SELECT @recordID = MIN(id) FROM @transferTable

WHILE @recordID IS NOT NULL
BEGIN
-- Update attempt
    UPDATE transferlog
    SET LastAttempt = GetDate()
    WHERE id = @recordID;
-- attempt
   SET @SQLCommand 'Insert into Azure.dbo.table blah blah' -- this part is broken right now
   print 'about to run sql command' --this prints
   Execute (@SQL Command)
   print 'ran sql' --this does not print
-- Update success
   UPDATE transferlog
   SET LastUpdate = GetDate()
   WHERE id=@recordID;
SELECT @recordID = MIN(id) FROM @transferTable WHERE id > @recordID
END
```

This is the sketch of how this stored procedure works.  Right now it is failing on the first table and I know why - there is a NOT NULL constraint on the Azure version of the table and one of the records that it is trying to insert has a NULL value in it.  That makes sense enoguh to me.

What does not make sense is the transfer log table is updating both the `LastAttempt` and `LastUpdate` columns for the first table which has the problematic NULL value in a column, but also for all the tables after it.

Why is this occurring?  The expected behavior by the author of the stored procedure though that the `LastUpdate` would run if and only if no error occurred but that does not seem to be the case.  How can we ensure that LastUpdated column is actually only updated if and only if no errors occurred when INSERT'ing into the Azure SQL Server database?

Comment: A batch does not *always* abort if an error occurs prior in the same batch. Executing something in a differed batch (with the unrecommended `EXEC (@SQL)` syntax) is unlikely to promote stop the outer batch.

Comment: You have no control-of-flow `begin/end` delimiters, that means all statements after the first update will execute regardless

Comment: `BEGIN`/`END` won't change anything here, @Stu . Enabling `XACT_ABORT` or using a `TRY...CATCH` would change the behaviour though.

Comment: @Stu sorry I just forgot to put in BEGIN/END.  Ok I will have to check,  I think the intended behavior is to try for each table independently.  So a `TRY...CATCH`  inside my `WHILE` loop would give me a way to handle if there's an issue.  Would `EXEC(@SQLStatement)` trigger the `CATCH` of a `TRY...CATCH` though since it seems to just get passed over in this instance?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not all errors in SQL Server are "equal". Some *will* not cause a batch to abort, and an error in a deferred batch, by using `EXEC (@SQL)` or (better) `sys.sp_executesql`, won't cause the outer batch to end (that is actually often desired behaviour as well), not to mention there are some that are "pre-batch" aborting as they occur at the time the batch is parsed.

Take the following batch:

```sql
SELECT 1;
EXEC sys.sp_executesql N'SELECT 1 / 0;';
SELECT 2;
EXEC sys.sp_executesql N'SELECT * FROM dbo.DoesNotExist;';
SELECT 3;
```

This will still result in the result sets with `2` and `3` being returned, despite that both statements executed in a deferred batch error.

In fact, if we move those statements out of deferred batches, then you *still* get `1` and `2`:

```sql
SELECT 1;
SELECT 1 / 0;
SELECT 2;
SELECT * FROM dbo.DoesNotExist;
SELECT 3;
```

Note, however, that `3` isn't returned, as referencing an object that doesn't exist *does* result in a batch aborting error in the same scope.

If you want to ensure that the batch is always aborted, then one method is to enable `XACT_ABORT`:

```sql
SET XACT_ABORT ON;
SELECT 1;
EXEC sys.sp_executesql N'SELECT 1 / 0;';
SELECT 2;
EXEC sys.sp_executesql N'SELECT * FROM dbo.DoesNotExist;';
SELECT 3;
```

This just results in `1` being returned. You may also want to ensure that you `BEGIN` and `COMMIT` a `TRANSACTION` so that on a failure anything is "automagically" rolled back.

Alternatively, you could use a `BEGIN TRY... CATCH`, however, I don't really see the benefit here:

```
BEGIN TRY
    SELECT 1;
    EXEC sys.sp_executesql N'SELECT 1 / 0;';
    SELECT 2;
    EXEC sys.sp_executesql N'SELECT * FROM dbo.DoesNotExist;';
    SELECT 3;
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    THROW;
END CATCH;
```